# how to swipe the children of a stackpanel to the another stackpanel in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm new to windows-phone. I have one doubt?
I'm having a stackpanel with Image and textblock as its children. Surrounding this stackpanel, a lot of stackpanels with different Image and textblock content. One of the surrounding stackpanel has no children. I want to swipe the any of the  stackpanel with children in right, left, top and bottom directions. The work, is to check the stackpanel in the swiped direction, whether it contains any children or not. If it does not contain any children, then, change the children of the main clicked stackpanel to the empty stackpanel..
And then clear the children in the main stackpanel. How to do it?

Please explain me with some coding parts.  Thank You for All....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the Google, you could find this WPF [realization](http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/06/wpf-animation-fifteen-puzzle-game.html#.UGWpHU196js) of [Fifteen Puzzel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteen_puzzle) Game in WPF.

You just need to "translate" it to Windows Phone 7.